# Which HTML and CSS standards reached W3C Recommendation status?

Tags: html, css, w3c, web-standards

Could anyone please tell me which HTML/XHTML and CSS versions reached "Recommendation" (not "Candidate Recommendation") status?

I tried to find the documents at http://www.w3.org/TR/tr-status-stds
and they appear to be:
1) "XHTML™ 1.0 The Extensible HyperText Markup Language (Second Edition)"
2) "Cascading Style Sheets (CSS1) Level 1 Specification"

Please correct me if I'm wrong. These are kinda neanderthal technologies...

Comment: My logic says that they would probably recommend what they use, so XHTML 1.0 Strict and maybe CSS 2.1

Answer (score 3):

XHTML 1.0 and 1.1 are Recommandation

HTML1, 2, 3 and 4 are Recommandation
HTML 5 is a Working Draft

CSS level 1 and level 2 are Recommandation
CSS level 2.1 (correction for the level2) is actually in a Last Call phase (since 2010-12-07), it was in a Proposed recommandation phase.

CSS level 3 is divided into modules, you can see an overview of each module and their maturity level on this page :
http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

If you not sure about what maturity level means, you can consult this document from w3c :
http://www.w3.org/2005/10/Process-20051014/tr#q73

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

That list looks complete...but I found it a little confusing. You could also try Wikipedia:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xhtml
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Html

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the W3C site and look: http://www.w3.org/standards/
Specificaly, you want this link: http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/htmlcss
Look on the right side for current status
XHTML is hardly "neanderthal".

Answer (score 0):

More or less what Tim said.

The reason why there are no CSS 3 modules in Recommendation is that they usually build on CSS2.1. As 2.1 isn’t a recommendation, the CSS3 modules (selectors) that are considered ready can’t graduate to recommendation status until it does. CSS 2.1 is close to becoming a rec now. It just has a few issues left to solve, and needs some work on the test suite.

CSS2.1 along with the CSS3 modules that the W3C consider to be stable are defined in the [CSS 2010 snapshot](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-2010/). All of these are considered safe to use and should become a recommendation soon.

HTML5 is quite new in the grand scheme of things, and will probably be a while before it becomes a Rec, although it shouldn’t be long before many of the browsers support all of the spec to some degree or other. A lot of HTML5 is already well supported in Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox and IE9.